# Unable to extend: TailwindCSS variants:

Tags: tailwind-css

I am looking to extend the margin style and add the variant `['even']` to it.

I can add the variant like so:

```
module.exports = {
  variants: {
    margin: ['even'],
  },
  theme: {
    ...
  }
}
```

It is my understanding that the above will override the margin styles default variants.

The documentation [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#even-child) shows the ability to extend a variant as to not remove all the defaults when adding the new variant (discussed more [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuring-variants)).

I have tried this and not been successful:

```
module.exports = {
  variants: {
    extend: {  
      margin: ['even'],
    },
  },
  theme: {
    ...
  }
}
```

I must be doing something wrong or have a typo?

Comment: Are you using Tailwind 2.0 or an older version? (I don't believe this is possible before 2.0)

Comment: This is the reason, I have 1.9.6 installed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I was unable to do this was because of my tailwindcss version being below 2.0. As [@Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359745/jon) suggested. Thanks! [2.0 release notes.](https://blog.tailwindcss.com/tailwindcss-v2)